# XML no válido genera doble comilla GENEXUS

Tags: xml, genexus

Foro:
En genexusXEv2 generador de java, tengo un procedimiento que genera un XML

RUTA = "C:\prueba.xml"

sdtfactura.id = 'comprobante'

```
DATO = sdtfactura.ToXml(1,0)
```

La etiqueta que me genera es con doble comillas cuando guardo a un archivo

`&i = dfwopen(RUTA, '', '')     if &i = 0
&i = dfwptxt(DATO, 9999)
&i = dfwnext()
Endif
&i = dfwclose( )

`

`"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>`
`<factura xmlns="""" id=""comprobante"" version=""1.1.0"">`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Deberías publicar el código de tu procedimiento, las propiedades del mismo y que generado estas usando (no es que tenga la respuesta, pero eso va a ayudar a los demás a dártelas)

Comment: Podrias usar las funciones que tiene GeneXus para manejo de xml. &Dato = sdtfactura.ToXml(1,0) &RUTA = "C:\prueba.xml" &XmlWriter.Open(&RUTA) //&XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument('UTF-8', 1) &XmlWriter.WriteRawText(&Dato) &XmlWriter.Close()

Comment: Si así fue utilice SDT y en la variable &Dato por ejemplo añadí la función Strreplace

Comment: Muy bien utilicé un SDT y añadí adicionalmente esto:                      
&XmlDato = &SDT_dato.ToXml(1,0)                                             
&XmlDato = strReplace(&XmlDato,'"', '')                                        
&XmlDato = strReplace(&XmlDato,'PROYECTO:', "PROYECTO:'")